# PHP splitting models based for related tables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I develop most of my apps using CodeIgniter, there is no strict MVC.  Generally, I just create models based on database tables or controllers.  However, I have two tables 'campaigns' and 'ads' that are related to one another.  So often, there will be "Get Ads By Campaign" and so forth.  Would you just create a campaign model and use that for everything? or create one for campaigns and one for ads and anything that uses 'ads' generally use the ads model?

Just looking for suggestions on keeping things organized.  Thank you!

EDIT:

Or, I could extend the 'Ads' model from the campaign model, so I always use `$this->campaign_model` reference ?

Comment: Generally one object should fullfil one job. If you can separate them, separate them.

Comment: I'd agree with @hakre. You never know when you might have 'Ads' that are not part of a campaign or vice-versa. Separate them and let them function independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do one for each and add convenience methods like `getAds` on the `Campaign` model and the corresponding ones on the `Ad` model.

Answer (score 2):

It is the matter of isolation. Each model should be designed to do its specific job. It may not sound useful for now but in the long run it will be useful if you later decide to introduce additional task in `ads` but not in `campaigns` or vice versa.